# SoftLayer_Location/getDatacenters API gives inconsistent response for different datacenters

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

The SoftLayer_Location getDatacenter API and it's response for *Dallas 09* and *San Jose 04* datacenters is pasted below:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Location/getDatacenters.json?objectFilter={"name":{"operation":"dal09"}}&objectMask=mask[groups]
```

`[{
  "id": 449494,
  "longName": "Dallas 9",
  "name": "dal09",
  "statusId": 2,
  "groups": [{
    "description": "All Datacenters in the USA",
    "id": 1,
    "locationGroupTypeId": 1,
    "name": "US",
    "securityLevelId": null,
    "locationGroupType": {
      "name": "VDR"
    }
  }, {
    "description": "na-usa-central-1",
    "id": 22,
    "locationGroupTypeId": 42,
    "name": "na-usa-central-1",
    "securityLevelId": null,
    "locationGroupType": {
      "name": "REGIONAL"
    }
  }, {
    "description": "COS Cross Region - US",
    "id": 1307,
    "locationGroupTypeId": 82,
    "name": "us",
    "securityLevelId": null,
    "locationGroupType": {
      "name": "PRICING"
    }
  }]
}]`

---

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Location/getDatacenters.json?objectFilter={"name":{"operation":"sjc04"}}&objectMask=mask[groups]

`[{
  "id": 2178495,
  "longName": "San Jose 4",
  "name": "sjc04",
  "statusId": 2,
  "groups": [{
    "description": "All Datacenters in the USA",
    "id": 1,
    "locationGroupTypeId": 1,
    "name": "US",
    "securityLevelId": null,
    "locationGroupType": {
      "name": "VDR"
    }
  }, {
    "description": "na-usa-west-2",
    "id": 64,
    "locationGroupTypeId": 42,
    "name": "na-usa-west-2",
    "securityLevelId": null,
    "locationGroupType": {
      "name": "REGIONAL"
    }
  }]
}]`

As we can see the `"locationGroupType": {"name": "PRICING"}` is not part of the response for *San Jose 04* datacenter. This is also being seen for *Washington* Datacenters.

This is the filter we're using to fetch the pricing with respect to *locationGroupId*. But since this attribute is not available for certain datacenters our code is unable to fetch the pricing for those datacenters. Is this expected or something has been changed in the APIs

Also referred to [Softlayer API verify order fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023962/softlayer-api-verify-order-fail) question, however the pricingLocationGroup attribute was not seen in getItems API call of SoftLayer_Product_Package.

Comment: Just to understand better, what is exactly you are trying to accomplish or obtain, afaik location groups are defined for specific design reason, if all should behave the same then it would have no reason to be designed in that way and have location groups per datacenter. Also it would be great if you could attach an image or point us out the PORTAL UI of what you require to verify if there´s truly a discrepancy as you mentioned.

Comment: According to the SoftLayer_Location API documentation.
```https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Location/265592/getPriceGroups.json```
```
[{
  "description": "Location Group 2",
  "id": 503,
  "locationGroupTypeId": 82,
  "name": "Location Group 2",
  "securityLevelId": null,
  "locationGroupType": {
    "name": "PRICING"
  }
}]```
```https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Location/154820/getPriceGroups.json```
However, the response of the above API (for dal06), is empty.
So, we wanted to understand the reason price group is not available for all.

Comment: Basically, we want to understand, how do we fetch the pricing for such locations, where "Price Group" is not present.